# Crossy Road on Android (Fire Stick) Issue

Tags: applications, bugs

My nephew plays Crossy Road on his Amazon Fire Stick Android device.

He's earned almost every different character.  He hasn't had to pay for any... he's earned them all by playing... a lot.

Suddenly, the game stopped working for him yesterday.  The icon is still there, but when he clicks on it, it does nothing.

What I've done for him:

1. Restarted the Fire Stick.  Didn't help.
2. Offered to attempt psychotherapy.  Refused.

I was thinking about just uninstalling it and then reinstalling it, but I'm afraid that will lose all of the characters he's earned.

How do I get Crossy Road working on his Fire Stick again without him losing all the character he earned?

Comment: Same thing happened to us, we tried unplugging and plugging back in, nothing. We tried uninstalling and reinstalling a different game on the fire stick to see if the levels would be saved. Unfortunately, even though we did not click "remove from cloud" and then just reinstalled the game no progress was saved. I gave up an uninstalled Crossy road itself and the same problem is still happening, the game is still unplayable. So definitely don't uninstall!

Comment: Thank you.  That is great help, because without your post, that would have been the next step.  Thank you for helping him navigate the treacherous pathways through this dark and difficult time in his life.

Comment: The acronym FWP can be taken in directions you didn't intend here. Because: crazy people.

Comment: @wbogacz Thanks... I had no idea... I'll edit the question to remove ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon say it's a known problem and they're working on it. Update in up to 3 days!

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a site with the info, or did you call them?  Glad it's not just his game, otherwise it would never get fixed.

Comment: I called them, they promised an email update. Son identifies with your nephew, so thinking a support group may be needed

Comment: And also one for parents.  Perhaps we can call it CRAP (Crossy Road Anonymous for Parents).

Comment: Good plan, but no need now - CROSSY ROAD IS BACK!